# Adobe LiveCycle font conversion

Tags: fonts, adobe, livecycle

I'm using Adobe LiveCycle to make some documents on server side.

During the development, I'm using Adobe LiveCycle Designer to create a new pdf template. When I design the template, I use "Times New Roman" font, but if I generate the PDF from the server and I check the PDF properties, I see that the used fonts are "TimesNewRomanPSMT" and "TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT".

I've not found an explanation of this behavior, please someone can explain me why this happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fonts are being substituted when the form is rendered on the server side. This generally happens when the fonts have not been embedded into the template itself using LiveCycle designer. If the server is unable to find a font, it substitutes it with one that it thinks is closer to the one you are using.

You can navigate to File > Form Properties > Save Options and enable "Embed fonts".
Please note that this will result in an increase in your form template size.

For more details, please review the following [link](http://blogs.adobe.com/formfeed/2011/05/fonts-are-big.html)

Please let me know if you have any other questions.

Thanks,

Armaghan

Comment: Thank you for your kindness. Your explanation is really clear.

Comment: No worries, let me know if you have any other LiveCycle questions and I will answer them on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Livecycle give you a option in case you are opening a XDP and the form used in the form is not available. There are two ways first you can choose some other font/ default fonts or can install that font.